# model with relation to other model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js and I have the following unsolved situation:
Assume you have two models:

```
var Person = Backbone.model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        age: 24
    }
});

var Car = Backbone.model.extend({
    defaults: {
        type: '',
        driving_person: null
    }
});
```

And I have a service which I can invoke by an ajax call and it return car json in the following format:

```
{
    car: {
        type: 'Honda Civic',
        driving_person: {
            name: 'dan',
            age: 13
        }
    }
}
```

I add also urlRoot property inside the car model that reference to that service.
Now I want to use fetch in order to load a specific car, but I would like the get the car model with a person MODEL in the driving_person property. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your car model must contain user_id or user_name or some property like that, 
so that you can take that data and do your embedding on the back end.

You also need to make use of `parse()` method of your model.
You override it to parse your json response from the server, 
and when you parse, you automatically create your User model in backbone
(or refer to it, if it is already created).

But I think that also you can do this while creating your car model, 
in it's `initialize()` method.

That may be even better.

However, if what you are asking is how you will select the proper car based on the user, when you request data from the server, then this logic is on the server side.
You need to implement it server side.

If you want to embed a driving_person within a model on a client side just like in your json response, just define your driving_person property, and it will have json object as its value.

If you want a new Backbone.Model embedded within car model, you will need to deal with `initialize()` of the car model.
Or even maybe `parse()`.

Edited:

If you want to embed a user model into car model after fetch, you need to override constructor method:

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({

    constructor: function(data, options){
        this.driving_person = new User(data.driving_person);
        delete data.driving_person;
        Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.call(this, data);
    }

    /// Your other model code like initialize, etc.
```

Edit 2:

If you want to avoid having a new driver model per each car (because maybe more cars will share same driver), then you should probably have a global variable (or even a collection), 
that takes Driver models.

It needs to be a global collection defined earlier in the code.

Then, you add driver to that global collection within this constructor that I gave you.

Let's say that you defined a global DriverCollection earlier in the code
(you do this by:

```
window.DriverCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Driver,
```

Then, you would make your car model like this:

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({   
    constructor: function(data, options){           
        if (!window.DriverCollection.find(function(driver){return driver.name == data.driving_person.name;}))
        {window.DriverCollection.add(driving_person);}
        data.driving_person = data.driving_person.name;
        Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.call(this, data);
    }       
    /// Your other Car model code like initialize etc.
```

This way, your Car constructor takes JSON data and adds to global DriverCollection the driver if it doesnt exist, and it sets your car's `driving_person` property to `name` property of the embedded json driver object.

You can of course also use other property to reference & seek your driver, like id or whatever.

This way you avoid duplication.

You need to have Driver model defined for this to work.

Comment: I really don't understand you suggestion. I wrote the response structure of my ajax call and I am looking for the correct way to creating Car model instance with Driver instance in the driving_person property. Can you put any code example?

Comment: It is a bit tricky because a User can have more cars I presume.
So if you create new model User for each car, you will duplicate your User models across many cars.

If this is not the case, I will edit my answer to give you the code.

Comment: My application is used only to display data and not to insert data. More then that, Driver can be related to only one car. And please, use Driver and not User because it is confusing :)

Comment: I just gave you the code you need to make to have embedded Driver model in every car model.

For foreign key approach I will add edit.

Comment: I don't know why you modify the constructor. I am fetching the data! Don't you need to make changes in model parse??

Comment: Well, you can do it there too. But you need to set the name of your future model, so its the same either way.

Comment: I think I understand you now. What do you think is the better - implement the parsing in the initialize, constructor or in parse?

Comment: Well, it is up to you. Backbone is known as non-opinionated framework.
Anyway, if you found out what you were interested in, don't forget to accept the answer.